# how to replace in C# from HTML

Tags: c#, string

```
    "<html><body style='background-color:Black;font-size:30px;color:#fff;'>
<html>\r\n<head><link href='http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/Styles/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />\r\n
<title>Finmin Aims to Halve Net Bad Loans of PSBs</title>\r\n<style
 type=\"text/css\">\r\nbody{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:18px;text-align:justify;}\r\n.w100{width:100%;}\r\n.fl-l{float:left;}\r\n.ffla{font-family:Arial,
 Helvetica, sans-serif;}\r\n.fs18{font-size:18px;}\r\n.mart10{margin-top:10px;}\r\n.fcred{color:#c81616;}\r\n.tc{text-align:center;}\r\n.tu{text-transform:uppercase;}\r\n.lh18{line-height:18px;}\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div class=\"w100 fl-l\">\r\n<div class=\"w100 fl-l ffla fs18 mart10 fcred ttunderline tc tu\">Finmin Aims to Halve Net Bad Loans of PSBs</div>\r\n\r\n<div class=\"w100 fl-l lh18 mart10\">Concernedover the rising bad loans of the state-run banks, the finance ministry is working out a plan to reduce their net non-performing assets (NPAs) to 1% of net advances by the end  Baand strict recovery policy. – www.economictimes.indiatimes.com</div>\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n</body><
/html>"
```

This is My HTML and I want to replace or remove    `<html>\r\n<head><link href='http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/Styles/style.css' 
    rel='stylesheet'  type='text/css' />\r\`   from given HTML.

I have tried following code:

```
string t= html.replace(" given remove   ", " ")
```

But not able to do 
please help me how I will do this?

Comment: I suggest using HtmlAgilityPack to parse your HTML into a DOM, then manipulate the nodes that way, rather than treating the HTML document as an opaque string.

Comment: Also, try not to use Regex to parse HTML in the future.

Comment: @AgentFire: He isn't using regex is he? `Replace` is a standard string method.

Comment: i have to replace  <html>\r\n<head><link href='http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/Styles/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />\r\n in this Html  Thats it cant we apply Replace command for this ?

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett specially for you I have mentioned "in the future".

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use string replacement for such requirements instead check and use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/). Secondly I think may be you don't want to invest your time due to `quick give me` situations and/or being dependent on some other utility tools.

Anyways live example **[here](http://rextester.com/ZWQPFC96416)** in your way.

### Example Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace TestApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string inputValue = "<html><body style='background-color:Black;font-size:30px;color:#fff;'><html>\r\n<head><link href='http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/Styles/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />\r\n<title>Finmin Aims to Halve Net Bad Loans of PSBs</title>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">\r\nbody{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:18px;text-align:justify;}\r\n.w100{width:100%;}\r\n.fl-l{float:left;}\r\n.ffla{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}\r\n.fs18{font-size:18px;}\r\n.mart10{margin-top:10px;}\r\n.fcred{color:#c81616;}\r\n.tc{text-align:center;}\r\n.tu{text-transform:uppercase;}\r\n.lh18{line-height:18px;}\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div class=\"w100 fl-l\">\r\n<div class=\"w100 fl-l ffla fs18 mart10 fcred ttunderline tc tu\">Finmin Aims to Halve Net Bad Loans of PSBs</div>\r\n\r\n<div class=\"w100 fl-l lh18 mart10\">Concernedover the rising bad loans of the state-run banks, the finance ministry is working out a plan to reduce their net non-performing assets (NPAs) to 1% of net advances by the end  Baand strict recovery policy. – www.economictimes.indiatimes.com</div>\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n</body></html>";
            string resultValue= inputValue.Replace("href='http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/Styles/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />\r\n", " ");
            Console.WriteLine("<span>Input value: </span>");
            Console.WriteLine(inputValue);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("<span>Output value: </span>");
            Console.WriteLine(resultValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No I m Posting Another Question Please Help me On that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893626/how-to-convert-html-using-replace-or-remove-commoand-c-sharp-or-java check this