# How to convert HTML using replace or remove commoand in C# or Java

Tags: c#, java, html

```
    HTML 1  I m getting this in string ->

    S=        
           "<html>  <head> <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'
             href='http://www.taxmann.com/css/taxmannstyle.css' /> 
                 </head>  <body ><html>
                <body style='background-color:Black;font-size:30px;color:#fff;'>
        <div id=\"digest\">\r\n   
                   <p class=\"threedigest\">ST : Extended period of limitation 
                cannot be invoked for not paying tax if there was divergence 
        of opinion during relevant 
                period and 
                some judgments were in favour of assessee, 
                as there could be no suppression/wilful mis-statement
         by assessee</p>\r\n   
                 </div></body></html></body></html>"
```

Note : I am getting  this HTML which is Correct

```
BUT    String HTML 2 ->

            "<html> 
                     <head> <link rel='stylesheet
                    ' type='text/css' href='http://www.taxmann.com/css/taxmannstyle.css' /> 
                     </head>  <body ><html><body style='background-color:Black;font-size:30px;color:#fff;'>
                    <html>\r\n<head>
                    <link href='http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/Styles/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
                    \r\n<title>Rs.560-crore tax evasion detected</title>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">
            \r\nbody
                    {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; 
                line-height:18px;text-align:justify;}
                    \r\n.w100{width:100%;}\r\n.fl-l{float:left;}\r\n.ffla{font-family:Arial, 
                Helvetica, sans-serif;}
                    \r\n.fs18{font-size:18px;}\r\n.mart10{margin-top:10px;}\r\n.fcred{color:#c81616;}
                \r\n.tc{text-align:center;}\r\n.tu{text-transform:uppercase;}\r\n.lh18{line-height:18px;}\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n
                <div class=\"w100 fl-l\">\r\n<div class=\"w100 fl-l ffla fs18 mart10 fcred ttunderline tc tu\">
                    Rs.560-crore tax 
vasion detected</div>\r\n\r\n<div class=\"w100 fl-l lh18 mart10\">
                The Central Excise Intelligence, 
Chennai Zone, has detected 164 cases involving excise
                 and service tax evasion of Rs.560 crore in 2012- 13.
     A total of 166 show cause notices
                 have been issued involving Rs.500 crore for 
    various central excise and service 
                tax cases during the year.
 – www.business-standard.com</div>\r\n\r\n
            </div>\r\n</body>\r\n
                    </html>\r\n</body>
    </html></body>
    </html>"
```

I want to Convert HTML 2 format same as Html1 format I tried Much but unable to do . I have tried to remove Some HTML Content as well but its not worked, I don't know how to convert Html2  same as it Html1 even I have also tried to Remove this using Java But not able to do Please help me ! Using  replace or remove command in any programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working with removing two unwanted html tags in line one     in your code i.e response from server have two html tags because of that your are not getting proper response. Try to remove all unwanted tags and align the html code

```
public class TestScriptClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String inputValue=" ";
      inputValue =inputValue+"<html><head> <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.taxmann.com/css/taxmannstyle.css' />"+ 
                    "</head>  <body ><html><body style='background-color:Black;font-size:30px;color:#fff;'>"+ 
                    "<html>\r\n<head> <link href='http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/Styles/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />"+ 
                    "\r\n<title>Rs.560-crore tax evasion detected</title>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">"+ 
                    "  \r\nbody{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; "+ 
                    " line-height:18px;text-align:justify;} \r\n.w100{width:100%;}\r\n.fl-l{float:left;}\r\n.ffla{font-family:Arial, "+ 
                    "Helvetica, sans-serif;} \r\n.fs18{font-size:18px;}\r\n.mart10{margin-top:10px;}\r\n.fcred{color:#c81616;}"+ 
                    " \r\n.tc{text-align:center;}\r\n.tu{text-transform:uppercase;}\r\n.lh18{line-height:18px;}\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n"+ 
                    "  <div class=\"w100 fl-l\">\r\n<div class=\"w100 fl-l ffla fs18 mart10 fcred ttunderline tc tu\">"+ 
                    "   Rs.560-crore tax "+ 
                    "vasion detected</div>\r\n\r\n<div class=\"w100 fl-l lh18 mart10\">"+ 
                    " The Central Excise Intelligence, "+ 
                    "Chennai Zone, has detected 164 cases involving excise"+ 
                    "  and service tax evasion of Rs.560 crore in 2012- 13."+ 
                    "  A total of 166 show cause notices"+ 
                    "   have been issued involving Rs.500 crore for "+ 
                    "  various central excise and service "+ 
                    "  tax cases during the year."+ 
                    "– www.business-standard.com</div>\r\n\r\n"+ 
                    " </div>\r\n</body>\r\n"+ 
                    "   </html>\r\n</body>"+ 
                    "  </html></body>"+ 
                    "   </html>";

      String resultValue= inputValue.replace("<html><head> <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.taxmann.com/css/taxmannstyle.css' /></head>  <body ><html>", " <html><head> <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.taxmann.com/css/taxmannstyle.css' />");

      System.out.println(resultValue);       
}
}
```