# How to Use replace command for in C#?

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string t="<html>  <head> <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.taxmann.com/css/taxmannstyle.css' />  </head>  <body ><html><body style='background-color:Black;font-size:30px;color:#fff;'><html>\r\n<head><link href='http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/Styles/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />\r\n<title>Finmin Aims to Halve Net Bad Loans of PSBs</title>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">\r\nbody{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:18px;text-align:justify;}\r\n.w100{width:100%;}\r\n.fl-l{float:left;}\r\n.ffla{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}\r\n.fs18{font-size:18px;}\r\n.mart10{margin-top:10px;}\r\n.fcred{color:#c81616;}\r\n.tc{text-align:center;}\r\n.tu{text-transform:uppercase;}\r\n.lh18{line-height:18px;}\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div class=\"w100 fl-l\">\r\n<div class=\"w100 fl-l ffla fs18 mart10 fcred ttunderline tc tu\">Finmin Aims to Halve Net Bad Loans of PSBs</div>\r\n\r\n<div class=\"w100 fl-l lh18 mart10\">Concernedover the rising bad loans of the state-run banks, the finance ministry is working out a plan to reduce their net non-performing assets (NPAs) to 1% of net advances by the end of the current financial year.</div>\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n</body></html></body></html>"



    string resultValue = t.Replace("<html><head> <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.taxmann.com/css/taxmannstyle.css' /></head> <body ><html>", " <html><head> </head> <body ><html>");  //its not working

    Console.WriteLine(resultValue);

}
```

This is my code But i m unable replace `resultValue`.

Comment: your space symbols in t and t.Replace pattern are mismatching

Comment: Please abstract your problem instead of copying your input here.

Comment: There is no replacement, because there is no match. `<html><head>` does not match `<html>  <head>`

Comment: In addition to what everyone else has said, your code doesn't even compile.  Next time please try to post code that compiles and run a spell-check.

Comment: By the way, `<html><head> </head> <body ><html>` is not valid html document.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to replace in C# from HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874131/how-to-replace-in-c-sharp-from-html)

Answer (score 2):

The `Replace` method takes *exact* strings.

In your original you have:

```
 />  </head>
```

But in the replace string you have:

```
 /></head>
```

Spaces are significant.

In this case, since this is HTML, I suggest using an HTML parser instead of `string.Replace`.

Two popular parsers are the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery). You use either one to read the HTML and rewrite what you need.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LyyJdMHQ this Original HTML i need replace

Comment: string resultValue = t.Replace("<html><head> <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.taxmann.com/css/taxmannstyle.css' /></head> <body ><html>", " <html><head> </head> <body ><html>");   with this

Answer (score 2):

The way you use it is fine, but it does not match against your input string as the phrase `<html>  <head>` is not the same as `<html><head>`. The spaces make the replace fail.

You can use a regular expression to match where you allow whitespaces between your tags or you can strip of all whitespaces after `>` and then replace the value.

Comment: pastebin.com/LyyJdMHQ this Original HTML i need replace

Comment: @user2148026 replace `\r\n` first and then replace the code you wanted to replace. Do not include spaces between the tags as your code on pastebin does not have spaces either.